# library for integer factorization in java or scala

Tags: java, scala, math, factorization

There are a lot of questions about how to implement factorization, however for production use, I would rather use an open source library to get something efficient and well tested right away.
The method I am looking for looks like this:

```
static int[] getPrimeFactors(int n)
```

it would return {2,2,3} for n=12

A library may also have an overload for handling long or even BigInteger types

The question is not about a particular application, it is about having a library which handles well this problem. Many people argue that different implementations are needed depending on the range of the numbers, in this regard, I would expect that the library select the most reasonable method at runtime.

By efficient I don't mean "world fastest" (I would not work on the JVM for that...), I just mean dealing with int and long range within a second rather than a hour.

Comment: How big a number do you need to be able to handle?

Comment: Often factors are used to find something else (assuming this is not all your program does). The most efficient solution may be to find whatever you are using factors for now directly.

Comment: @Thilo: the range of int would do. I guess that a decent library would also provide an implementation for long and BigInteger.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: finding the prime factor is a fairly common task, I don't remember why I was needing it last time, anyway, this time I need them for testing if a polynomial is primitive or not. (for that a library may exist, but I do want to implement this part myself). I don't really understand your second sentence :-S

Comment: My second statement means, there may be a more efficient way to achieve what you want. In your case, you want to determine if the greatest common divisor is 1 or not. This could be done as a single function. Say you have lots of coefficients but one is 1, you don't need to determine all the factors of the other coefficients.

Answer (score 4):

It depends what you want to do. If your needs are modest (say, you want to solve [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net) problems), a simple implementation of Pollard's rho algorithm will find factors up to ten or twelve digits instantly; if that's what you want, let me know, and I can post some code. If you want a more powerful factoring program that's written in Java, you can look at the source code behind Dario Alpern's [applet](http://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM); I don't know about a test suite, and it's really not designed with an open api, but it does have lots of users and is well tested. Most of the heavy-duty open-source factoring programs are written in C or C++ and use the GMP big-integer library, but you may be able to access them via your language's foreign function interface; look for names like [gmp-ecm](http://ecm.gforge.inria.fr/), [msieve](http://msieve.sourceforge.net/), [pari](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) or [yafu](http://sourceforge.net/projects/yafu/). If those don't satisfy you, a good place to ask for more help is the [Mersenne Forum](http://mersenneforum.org/).

Comment: Is Pollard's rho _guaranteed_ to find a factor if one exists?  I had thought not, which may render it unsuitable.

Comment: @RexKerr: I think the answer is yes, Pollard rho is guaranteed to find a factor if one exists, though I'm not sure I can prove it. You may have to switch to a different random-number generator if the first one you try runs into a cycle.

Comment: @RexKerr: [Pollard's Rho is probabilistic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm#Complexity).

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. About Pollard's Rho: According to Wikipedia this algorithm always fail for prime numbers, so it would require to run a primality test first :-S But as you said, for a couple of project Euler problems it is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to solve your problem, rather than get what you are asking for, you want a table.  You can precompute it using silly slow methods, store it, and then look up the factors for any number in microseconds.  In particular, you want a table where the smallest factor is listed in an index corresponding to the number--much more memory efficient if you use trial division to remove a few of the smallest primes--and then walk your way down the table until you hit a 1 (meaning no more divisors; what you have left is prime).  This will take only two bytes per table entry, which means you can store everything on any modern machine more hefty than a smartphone.

I can demonstrate how to create this if you're interested, and show how to check that it is correct with greater reliability than you could hope to achieve with an active community and unit tests of a complex algorithm (unless you ran the algorithm to generate this table and verified that it was all ok).

Comment: I guess you're assuming int and ignoring the generalization to long and BigInteger. Even with int the table is large, and unnecessary. Trial division by 2 and the odd numbers from 3 to sqrt(2^31-1) is simple and fast with no auxiliary storage required.

Comment: @user448810 - Trial division by 20k numbers is fast enough for you?  Why then did you bother asking?  This is trivial to implement.

Comment: You have me confused with the original poster. I was merely pointing out that for ranges where a table is small enough to be sensible the table isn't needed because trial division is sufficient.

Comment: @user448810 - Whoops, I did get you confused.  But, again, trial division is on the order of a thousand times slower than the table approach.  So it rather depends on what you are doing, doesn't it?  Since the OP wanted an efficient approach for int, presumably trial division is _not_ sufficient.

Comment: I think we are in violent agreement here. The problem is that the original poster modified his requirement in the comment to say that it would be nice to handle long and BigInteger. A table is already straining for int (it has a billion entries, which would require a significant amount of time just to read from disk into memory). I discuss [factor tables](http://programmingpraxis.com/2012/05/08/factor-tables) at my blog, as well as lots of other prime number stuff.

Comment: @user448810 - If you remove the first few primes via trial division--up to 7, say--then you reduce your table size considerably (to ~23% of the original).  You only need numbers up to size sqrt(2^31), which fits in two bytes.  So you can fit it all in ~1G of memory.  That takes ~10s to read in, but otherwise is unlikely to strain resources on a modern machine and will be extremely fast.

Comment: Thanks for this alternative. The spirit of my question was "is there a library which implement integer factorization efficiently and with a simple interface". Something which would sort out all the discussions here: you need the prime factors of a number, you just use one of the few method of this library and you get a great implementation for the range of numbers considered. In short, my application is not relevant to the question.

Comment: @acapola I think what Rex has shown is that your application is *very* relevant. For some cases loading a 1gb table is the best way. For others it's total overkill. There's no one-size-fits-all function possible.

Answer (score 0):

> I need them for testing if a polynomial is primitive or not.

This is faster than trying to find the factors of all the numbers.

```
public static boolean gcdIsOne(int[] nums) {
    int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int num : nums) {
        if (num > 0 && smallest < num)
            smallest = num;
    }
    OUTER:
    for (int i = 2; i * i <= smallest; i = (i == 2 ? 3 : i + 2)) {
        for (int num : nums) {
            if (num % i != 0)
                continue OUTER;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I was not expecting this. I should have been more precise: I am working with a prime p and a monic irreducible polynomial f(x) with coefficients in Zp. I think the algorithme in this case is more complex (in my book it involves modular exponentiation, the exponent being each prime factors of p-1)

Answer (score -2):

I tried this function in scala. Here is my result:

```
def getPrimeFactores(i: Int) = {
  def loop(i: Int, mod: Int, primes: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
    if (i < 2) primes      // might be i == 1 as well and means we are done
    else {
      if (i % mod == 0) loop(i / mod, mod, mod :: primes)
      else loop(i, mod + 1, primes)
    }
  }
  loop(i, 2, Nil).reverse
}
```

I tried it to be as much functional as possible.

`if (i % mod == 0) loop(i / mod, mod, mod :: primes)` checks if we found a divisor. If we did we add it to primes and divide i by mod.

If we did not find a new divisor, we just increase the divisor.

`loop(i, 2, Nil).reverse` initializes the function and orders the result increasingly.

Comment: There's no need to reset to 2, since `mod` is already the smallest prime divisor of `i`

Comment: Thanks for this source code, but I am looking for an open source library with decent unit test suite, several users... something like apache.commons.math, which as far as I can see, do not implement such method.